# In Dates array remove same day dates in swift iOS

Tags: arrays, swift, date

In Dates array remove same day dates and get only other day dates.

Dates Input::

**[2023-10-16 09:13:07 +0000, 2023-10-17 09:13:07 +0000, 2023-10-14 09:13:07 +0000, 2023-10-15 09:13:07 +0000, 2023-10-16 09:13:07 +0000, 2023-10-110 09:13:07 +0000, 2023-10-16 09:13:07 +0000, 2023-10-14 09:13:07 +0000,  2023-10-16 09:13:07 +0000, 2023-10-15 09:13:07 +0000]**

Expected Output::

**[2023-10-17 09:13:07 +0000, 2023-10-16 09:13:07 +0000, 2023-10-13 09:13:07 +0000, 2023-10-10 09:13:07 +0000]**

I have tried as below have to give proper second date for comparison.

```
    var newFeedsDates = [Date]()
    var otherDayDates = [Date]()
    func getOtherDayDates() -> [Date] {
        for (index, element) in newFeedsDates.enumerated() {
            print("Item \(index): \(element)")
            let second = newFeedsDates(index + 1) // getting error as -> Cannot call value of non-function type '[Date]'
            let sameDay = Calendar.current.isDate(element, equalTo: Second, toGranularity: .day)
            printLog("isSameDay:: \(sameDay)")
            if !sameDay {
                otherDayDates.append(element)
            }
        }
        return otherDayDates
    }
```

Comment: In your Dates Input: "2023-10-110 09:13:07 +0000" , a typo I guess?

Comment: You say "In Dates array remove same day dates and get only other day dates." It isn't clear what you mean. Are you saying that you want your function to filter a list of Dates to only those dates that have a unique year/month/day? (A unique day on the calendar.) If so, your desired output breaks that rule, since your input array contains 3 dates on `2023-10-16`

Comment: Or are you saying that you only want the output to contain 1 Date for any given year/month/day? If you only want the result of the function to contain a single Date for a given year/month/day, **which** Date should it contain? The first one that appears in the input array?

Comment: "newFeedsDates(index + 1) // getting error as -> Cannot call value of non-function type '[Date]'" - you have a syntax error here. You should use [] to dereference an array, not (), which Swift interprets as a function, hence the error about a function.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Calendar` function `startOfDay` together with a `Set`

```
let unique = Set(newFeedsDates.map(Calendar.current.startOfDay(for:)))
```

or if you want an array you can initialise one directly

```
Array(Set(newFeedsDates.map(Calendar.current.startOfDay(for:))))
```

or by calling a function on the set that returns an array like do a sort

```
Set(newFeedsDates.map(Calendar.current.startOfDay)).sorted(by: >)
```

Comment: Note that the desired output shown in the question would indicate that using `startOfDay(for:)` is not the desired result. The question needs more clarification.

Comment: @HangarRash good point, I think my answer makes sense but as you point out it doesn’t match the expected outcome.

Answer (score 0):

```
func getOtherDayDates(inputDates: [Date]) -> [Date] {
    // Extract unique dates (ignoring time)
    let uniqueDates = Array(Set(inputDates.map { Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: $0) }))
    
    // Sort the unique dates in descending order
    let sortedUniqueDates = uniqueDates.sorted(by: { $0 > $1 })
    
    return sortedUniqueDates
}
```

Comment: @user22733877: please [edit] and clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to group the array with `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` and get the `keys`

```
let unique = Array(Dictionary(grouping: newFeedsDates, by: Calendar.current.startOfDay).keys)
```

or to de-duplicate the dates literally

```
let unique = Array(Dictionary(grouping: newFeedsDates, by: {$0}).keys)
```